# Can't open and save files on some devices with Android file-dialogs library

Tags: java, android

I'm using the following library to open and save files:

https://github.com/RustamG/file-dialogs

However, on some devices, I get the following error. I've checked and all necessary permissions are granted, and this works on my Samsung Galaxy S8, but not my Galaxy Tab A.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: vlab.itpc, PID: 7572 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Files list is null. Please make sure that you have read permission to this directory. Have you added android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to your AndroidManifest.xml? at com.rustamg.filedialogs.FileListAdapter.<init>(FileListAdapter.java:31) at com.rustamg.filedialogs.FileDialog$UpdateFilesTask.onPostExecute(FileDialog.java:251)...
```

My code is the following:

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString(FileDialog.EXTENSION, ".txt");
openFileDialog.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.AppTheme);
openFileDialog.setArguments(args);
openFileDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), OpenFileDialog.class.getName());
```

Can you help? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: That occurs on Android Q i think.

Comment: @blackapps Yes that could be it. Do you have any idea how to fix this to support Android Q?

Comment: For the time being you can add legacyExternalStorage true to manifest file. But for R that does not work anymore.

Comment: android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work now. Any idea what works for Android R in advance?

Comment: getFilesDir(), getExternalFilesDir(), getExternalFilesDirs(), Storage Access Framework and MediaStore.

Comment: Ok thanks. Feel free to add an answer so I can mark the question as answered